# Best way to encode rest calls

Tags: javascript, rest

I have a rest call that sends addresses to the back-end.  When an address contains a / e.g. c/o (corner of) I get a 400(bad request...  i've tried to encodeURIComponent(query) but even though the address is encoded it still gives me the same error.  i'm planning on replacing each occurance of / with $ in the rest call and then replacing the $ with a / again on the back-end.  Is this the only way to go about this or is there a propper way of doing this?

Comment: Can you share code?

Comment: Do you send it with GET or POST?

Comment: I send it with GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forward slash or `/` is a special char in URI encodings, it is used to separate arguments for the path to the file we want to access. So it obviously can not be used as we please. The `encodeURIComponent` function from Jquery will encode this character but it will be interpreted by your server as a keyword in most cases.

**Your solutions are:**

Either send using **POST**, which is the cleanest way to send text without having to care about its encoding.

Or replace the `/` with its html enity code which is: `&sol;`, that way, you can send it via **GET** and it will still be understood by HTML as a `/` but no longer as a special character.

Hope it helps

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` does encode `/`

Comment: Thanks a lot @RDardelet for the very clear explanation.  Works fine now!!!

Comment: Correct, i didn't say it right, i'll correct that thx

Comment: You're welcome @user2094257